# Chrome Spell Check Not Functioning

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

Chrome isn't spell checking for me. I have `Use a web service to help resolve spelling errors` enabled, but in `chrome://settings/languages` under `Languages`, `Spell check` it shows `Disabled`.

I've tried disabling and re-enabling `Use a web service to help resolve spelling errors` to no avail. How can I enayble spell chek?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click in a text editing field, and select `Spellcheck` and then check the `Check the spelling of text fields` option. This feature is oddly not included in Chrome's settings page.

[image: Screenshot showing check the spelling of text fields]

Comment: The option is not available on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Just found out you need to select your region. i.e. "English (United States)" instead of just "English". Then you will see the options ;)

Comment: Underrated answer. It is crucial to select the region. Even if you have "English" selected as your language, it won't do proper spell check. You should add "English (United States)" and remove "English".